# use of list in python program is showing error value

Tags: python

```
a=[1 , 2, 3,  4, 7, 8, 9]
b=[7, 13, 15]
c=b
print c, b
c=a[:]
print c, b
```

The first print gives me `[7, 13, 15], [7, 13, 15]` but in the second case `b` differs from `c`. Why do I get this result?
`c` is having the copy of `a` but the value of `b` is not changing even though `b` and `c` pointing the same object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c` is getting reassigned. It *was* pointing at the same object as `b`, but is now pointing at a copy of `a` instead.

If you had written `c[:]=a[:]` in your penultimate line, you would be replacing *contents* of `c` instead of its reference (as you did in your example), and the output would have been as you expected (`[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9] [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]`).